# Check if two vertices belongs to edge loop

Tags: python, mesh

Check if two vertices belongs to edge loop in object mode

[image]

Comment: something from https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31797/111042 perhaps

Comment: @james_t Thank you but it's not working !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code so we can help you figure out what you're doing wrong.